# How to avoid repetition defining a single Ajax Error Function

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, error-handling, laravel-blade

I'm using laravel for my project. And in my project there exists many ajax requests. For error handling i'm using this code partition.

```
error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
    if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
        alert('Bağlantı sağlanamadı.\n Lütfen internet bağlantınızı kontrol ediniz.');
    } else if (jqXHR.status === 404) {
        alert('Sayfa bulunamadı. [404]');
    } else if (jqXHR.status === 401) {
        window.location.replace('{{ route('login') }}');
    } else if (jqXHR.status === 500) {
        alert('Sunucu Hatası [500].');
    } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
        alert('Requested JSON parse failed.'+ jqXHR.responseText);
    } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
        alert('Time out error.');
    } else if (exception === 'abort') {
        alert('Ajax istemi durduruldu.');
    } else {
        alert('Beklenmeyen Hata.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
    }
},
```

I'm repeating myself for every request.

I want to write like `error: '{{ ajaxError() }}'`

as helper method. But i couldn't handle it. Is there anyway to do it in blade. I don't want to repeat myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably outputting a callback name from blade is not the best solution

If you use JQuery, you could attach a global error handler to every page: (place this at the start of your pages' scripts)

```
    $(document).ajaxError(function (event, jqXHR, settings, exception) 
    {
         if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
            alert('Bağlantı sağlanamadı.\n Lütfen internet bağlantınızı kontrolediniz.');
        } else if (jqXHR.status === 404) {
            alert('Sayfa bulunamadı. [404]');
        } else if (jqXHR.status === 401) {
            window.location.replace('{{ route('login') }}');
        } else if (jqXHR.status === 500) {
        alert('Sunucu Hatası [500].');
        } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
        alert('Requested JSON parse failed.'+ jqXHR.responseText);
        } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
        alert('Time out error.');
        } else if (exception === 'abort') {
        alert('Ajax istemi durduruldu.');
        } else {
        alert('Beklenmeyen Hata.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    } );
```

This way you don't even have to specify a error callback for every request, but everytime a ajax call will return an error the global callback will be executed

If you don't want yo use jquery you can define a single callback function:

```
function errorCallback (event, jqXHR, settings, exception) 
{
     if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
        alert('Bağlantı sağlanamadı.\n Lütfen internet bağlantınızı kontrolediniz.');
    } else if (jqXHR.status === 404) {
        alert('Sayfa bulunamadı. [404]');
    } else if (jqXHR.status === 401) {
        window.location.replace('{{ route('login') }}');
    } else if (jqXHR.status === 500) {
    alert('Sunucu Hatası [500].');
    } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
    alert('Requested JSON parse failed.'+ jqXHR.responseText);
    } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
    alert('Time out error.');
    } else if (exception === 'abort') {
    alert('Ajax istemi durduruldu.');
    } else {
    alert('Beklenmeyen Hata.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
    }
}
```

and attach it to every ajax request:

```
error: errorCallback
```

Comment: What is the best practice storing errorCallback function ? different js file ? or inside a blade template ? and include master page. Because if the status is 401 i'm redirecting to login page. And it is a laravel function. What is your offer. (By the way, Thank you for your help)

Comment: if there wasn't the instruction `{{ route('login') }}` i'd say the best place to store the script would be an external .js file included on top of every page. But, if you have to use blade to print the URL, simply put the function definition at the top of your master page, inside a `<script>` tag

Comment: Normally i think about first one like you prefer. But i don't want to hardcode my login url. And i have not too many javascript functions. And i have a folder ajax under views directory. Inside ajax folder i decided to create master.blade.php and i will extend this js function for all ajax views. But it is not good also. Because of this reason i asked to you.

Comment: if you have a master page putting the function definition in there is a resonable choice for me....